# terraform create dynamic suricata rules

Tags: terraform

im using the following code to write aws network firewall suricata rules :

yaml :

```
rule_groups:
  - name: "APPSTREAM"
    allowed-domains:
     - ".github.com"
     - ".google.com"
    source: "10.143.80.0/24"

  - name: "TEST"
    allowed-domains:
     - ".microsoft.com"
     - ".amazonaws.com"
    source: "10.143.70.0/24"
```

terraform code :

```
locals {
  list = yamldecode(file("${path.module}/settings.yaml"))["rule_groups"]
  fw_group_rule = flatten([for rule in local.list : {
    "name"            = rule.name
    "allowed-domains" = rule.allowed-domains
    "definition"      = rule.source
    }
  ])
}

resource "aws_networkfirewall_rule_group" "limit-Domain-Access-v1" {
  name     = "suricata-automation-test"
  capacity = 1000
  type     = "STATEFUL"
  rule_group {
    rule_variables {
      ip_sets {
        key = "SQUID_EP"
        ip_set {
          definition = ["10.143.60.158/32","10.143.60.17/32","10.143.60.164/32"]
        }
      }
      dynamic "ip_sets" {
        for_each = local.fw_group_rule
        content {
          key = ip_sets.value.name
          ip_set {
            definition = [ip_sets.value.definition]
          }
        }
      }
    }
    rules_source {
      rules_string = <<EOF
        %{for index,i in local.fw_group_rule~}  
        %{for url in i.allowed-domains}
        pass http ֿֿֿֿֿ${"$"}${i.name} any -> $SQUID_EP any (http.host; dotprefix; content:"${url}"; endswith; msg:"matching HTTP allowlisted FQDNs"; priority:1; flow:to_server, established; sid:${index + 1}; rev:1;)
        %{endfor}
        %{endfor~}
      EOF
 }
}
  tags = {
    Name = "suricata-automation-test"
  }
}

output "fw-group-rule" {
  value = <<EOF
    %{for index,i in local.fw_group_rule~}
    %{for url in i.allowed-domains}
    pass http ֿֿֿֿֿ${"$"}${i.name} any -> $SQUID_EP any (http.host; dotprefix; content:"${url}"; endswith; msg:"matching HTTP allowlisted FQDNs"; priority:1; flow:to_server, established; sid:1; rev:1;)
    %{endfor}
    %{endfor~}
  EOF
}
```

My problem is when i am trying to loop over the "rules_source" section, it creates a line of string for every `${i.name}` and `${url}` , and my problem is that the `sid:${index + 1}` section stays the same for every line and i need it to be unique for every line

example result : search for the sid

```
                  +         pass http ֿֿֿֿֿ$APPSTREAM any -> $SQUID_EP any (http.host; dotprefix; content:".github.com"; endswith; msg:"matching HTTP allowlisted FQDNs"; priority:1; flow:to_server, established; **sid:1**; rev:1;)
                  +         
                  +         pass http ֿֿֿֿֿ$APPSTREAM any -> $SQUID_EP any (http.host; dotprefix; content:".google.com"; endswith; msg:"matching HTTP allowlisted FQDNs"; priority:1; flow:to_server, established; **sid:1**; rev:1;)
                  +         
                  +                 
                  +         pass http ֿֿֿֿֿ$TEST any -> $SQUID_EP any (http.host; dotprefix; content:".microsoft.com"; endswith; msg:"matching HTTP allowlisted FQDNs"; priority:1; flow:to_server, established; **sid:2**; rev:1;)
                  +         
                  +         pass http ֿֿֿֿֿ$TEST any -> $SQUID_EP any (http.host; dotprefix; content:".amazonaws.com"; endswith; msg:"matching HTTP allowlisted FQDNs"; priority:1; flow:to_server, established; **sid:2**; rev:1;)
```

wanted result:

```
                  +         pass http ֿֿֿֿֿ$APPSTREAM any -> $SQUID_EP any (http.host; dotprefix; content:".github.com"; endswith; msg:"matching HTTP allowlisted FQDNs"; priority:1; flow:to_server, established; sid:1; rev:1;)
                  +         
                  +         pass http ֿֿֿֿֿ$APPSTREAM any -> $SQUID_EP any (http.host; dotprefix; content:".google.com"; endswith; msg:"matching HTTP allowlisted FQDNs"; priority:1; flow:to_server, established; sid:2; rev:1;)
                  +         
                  +                 
                  +         pass http ֿֿֿֿֿ$TEST any -> $SQUID_EP any (http.host; dotprefix; content:".microsoft.com"; endswith; msg:"matching HTTP allowlisted FQDNs"; priority:1; flow:to_server, established; sid:3; rev:1;)
                  +         
                  +         pass http ֿֿֿֿֿ$TEST any -> $SQUID_EP any (http.host; dotprefix; content:".amazonaws.com"; endswith; msg:"matching HTTP allowlisted FQDNs"; priority:1; flow:to_server, established; sid:4; rev:1;)
```

Answer (score 0):

solution

imported the yaml with python and wrote it into suricata_rules file , the used it in the terraform as following

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import yaml
with open('settings.yaml', 'rb') as f:
        config = yaml.safe_load(f)
core_config = config['rule_groups']

i = 0

for workload in core_config:
  for domain in (workload['allowed-domains']):
    i = i+1
    print(f'pass http ${workload["name"]} any -> $SQUID_EP any (http.host; dotprefix; content:"{domain}"; endswith; msg:"matching HTTP allowlisted FQDNs"; priority:1; flow:to_server, established; sid:{i}; rev:1;)')
```

```
locals {
  list = yamldecode(file("${path.module}/settings.yaml"))["rule_groups"]
  fw_group_rule = flatten([for rule in local.list : {
    "name"            = rule.name
    "allowed-domains" = rule.allowed-domains
    "definition"      = rule.source
    "policy"          = rule.policy
    }
  ])
}


resource "aws_networkfirewall_rule_group" "limit-Domain-Access-v1" {
  name     = "suricata-automation-test"
  capacity = 1000
  type     = "STATEFUL"
  rule_group {
    rule_variables {
      ip_sets {
        key = "SQUID_EP"
        ip_set {
          definition = ["10.143.60.158/32","10.143.60.17/32","10.143.60.164/32"]
        }
      }
      dynamic "ip_sets" {
        for_each = local.fw_group_rule
        content {
          key = ip_sets.value.name
          ip_set {
            definition = [ip_sets.value.definition]
          }
        }
      }
    }

    rules_source {
      rules_string = file(suricata_rules)
 }
}
  tags = {
    Name = "suricata-automation-test"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, where the signature ID would be 1431,1432 ..etc

```
        %{for url in i.allowed-domains}
    pass http ֿֿֿֿֿ${"$"}${i.name} any -> $SQUID_EP any (http.host; dotprefix; content:"${url}"; endswith; msg:"matching HTTP allowlisted FQDNs"; priority:1; flow:to_server, established; sid:143${index(i.allowed-domains,url)}; rev:1;)
    %{endfor}
```